# ffprobe missing title tag with mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have an mp4 file with a video stream and an audio stream. The audio stream has a title that is shown both by VLC and by Mediainfo.

If I open this file (or any other mp4 file with audio track titles) with this ffprobe command

ffprobe -i input.mp4 -show_streams

the title tag is missing. Even if I set the track title with ffmpeg -metadata:s:a:0 title="my title", the title tag is added/edited correctly by ffmpeg but ffprobe still doesn't see it (other media players do however).

Is this a bug with ffprobe? How can I get audio streams title tag to show?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Submit a [feature request](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: Do you mean `StreamTitle` tag? Is it shown by `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags`?

Answer (score 0):

If a stream has a valid tag called "title", ffprobe should show it near the end of the stream listing.  Even if you only enter `ffprobe input.mp4`, ffprobe will show stream titles like this, the same way ffmpeg does:

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English DTS Core 5.1 Surround @ 1536kbps
```

Perhaps the 'title' you're seeing in VLC and mediainfo is entered in some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my ffprobe (latest version) does not show the title row like in your example for mp4 files that have a valid title tag (and I know that tag is present because mediainfo and vlc show it, and because I have explicitly added it with ffmpeg)

Comment: Does ffmpeg show it?

Comment: I've been able to confirm this.  What I see is:
(1) Most stream titles do not appear, though some appear as "handler_name".
(2) Problem is with mp4s, not with mkvs.
(3) Problem in ffmpeg and ffprobe.
(4) I have two versions, problem in both: version N-100776-g2687070d9b and  N-101189-g5a4f0d9b94.  To do a bug report for ffmpeg, they will want you to compile the latest head version to make sure it hasn't already been fixed.

Comment: Also, when you add a stream title tag, it is shown in the output section of the ffmpeg output, and mediainfo can read it, but ffmpeg/probe can't see it when they look at the file.

Comment: I should have specified that the problem only verifies with mp4, not on mkv. What you say in your last comments is exactly what I have experienced

Comment: Same problem here. Any news?

Comment: I doubt there will be any news until someone files a bug report with ffmpeg.